# WPF bound DataGrid - Can I add an unbound column to show status?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

**Context**

C# WPF desktop application using Visual Studio 2015

**Issue**

I have a DataGrid bound to a List< T > object showing the user rows of data that are about to be processed. As they are processed I want to have an extra "Status" column on this DataGrid to indicate the success or otherwise of the processing of each row.

**Question**

How do I go about manupulating this extra column?  I've considered two approaches:

1. Change the bound data to include a Status element.  This is tricky however because the bound objects are obtained directly from an externally sourced API hence the structure is fixed.
2. Add an unbound column to the DataGrid (see example below).  This is my prefered approach but I don't know how to access the unbound cells to update status as each row is processed.

**Example**

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="ordersGrid" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,5,0,0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding /}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last update date" Binding="{Binding LastUpdateDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MMM/yy HH:mm:ss\}}" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order id" Binding="{Binding OrderId}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sales channel" Binding="{Binding SalesChannel}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" Binding="{Binding OrderTotal.CurrencyCode}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding OrderTotal.Amount, StringFormat=N2}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number of items" Binding="{Binding NumberOfItemsShipped}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding ShippingAddress.City}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="County" Binding="{Binding ShippingAddress.StateOrRegion}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding ShippingAddress.CountryCode}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The grid is displayed to the user and the Status column should initially be blank.  When the user hits a proceed button I'd like to populate the Status column with a success or fail message as each row of data is committed to a database.

..the grid is currently populated in the code behind with...

```
orders = new List<WebServiceOrders.Order>();

orders = WebAPI.ListOrders(ordersClient.Client, LastImportedDateTime).OrderBy(o => o.LastUpdateDate).ToList();
```

WebServiceOrders.Order *doesn't* have a Status property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a perfectly normal practice to wrap each line of data with a ViewModel before binding it to a list control like a DataGrid. This allows you an easy way to add extra properties, and an easy way to implement context specific commands at a row level - all without changing the original data item.

So you will have a `List<MyRowViewModel>` which is bound to the grid. `MyRowViewModel` could look like this:

```
public class MyRowViewModel
{
    public MyRowViewModel(WebServiceOrders.Order order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }

    public WebServiceOrders.Order Order { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; } //note you'll need to implement property notification
}
```

Once you've retrieved your original list of data objects, create a new list containing the wrapped objects:

```
var orders = WebAPI.ListOrders();
var myWrappedList = (from order
                    in orders 
                    select new MyRowViewModel(order))
                    .ToList();
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = myWrappedList;
```

Of course that is just pseudo code - you would be better off assigning the MyRowViewModel items to an ObservableCollection which you then bind to. You can then explicitly define your grid columns and bind them to the appropriate properties.

Comment: That works a treat and is a really useful concept for other projects I'm looking at - thanks.